# Find the differences between 2 Excel worksheets?

Tags: excel

I have two excel files with the same structure:  they both have 1 column with data.  One has 800 records and the other has 805 records, but I am not sure which of the 5 in the 805 set are not in the 800 set.  Can I find this out using Excel?

Comment: Note that if using a VLOOKUP solution you are assuming the values in your data are exclusive. For example, if the extra 5 rows' data repeats already existing values, then they won't be identified.

Comment: Correct.  And in that case of a repeating value, VLOOKUP will return the result from the first match.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

vlookup is your friend!

Position your column, one value per row, in column A of each spreadsheet.
in column B of the larger sheet, type

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'[Book2.xlsb]SheetName'!$A:$A,1,FALSE)
```

Then copy the formula down as far as your column of data runs.

Where the result of the formula is FALSE, that data is not in the other worksheet.

Comment: Can you explain what everything means?

Comment: A1 is the value we are searching for -- '[Book2.xlsb]SheetName'!$A:$A is where we are looking for it -- 1 indicates to return the value on the same row as the "match" from the first column of the range searched -- False is used to prevent "fuzzy" searches and force all matches to be exact

Answer (score 21):

It might seem like a hack, but I personally prefer copying the cells as text (or exporting as a CSV) into [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) or any other diff tool. Assuming the two sheets contain *mostly* identical data, Winmerge will show the differences immediately.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more work than writing a simple formula where the data is already contained?

Comment: Nick: There's always more than one way to crack a nut, but there's no right or wrong way to do it so long as you use the tools you're comfortable with.

Comment: I didn't say you were wrong...  It just seems a bit complicated to me when Excel has the tools already built in.  Once I get a result in the external tool, I'm probably going to need to bring it back to Excel to work with anyway.

Answer (score 19):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) provides a Workbook Compare feature: **Edit -> Compare Document**

Comment: Additionally, this feature also lets you Accept or Reject Changes into the document...so merging is a piece of cake!

Comment: I think it's the best solution with detailed changes view.

Comment: It has been moved to *Edit -> Track changes -> Compare Document*

Answer (score 15):

Easy way: Use a 3rd sheet to check.

Say you want to find differences between Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.

1. Go to Sheet 3, cell A1, enter
   `=IF(Sheet2!A1<>Sheet1!A1,"difference","")`.
2. Then select all cells
   of sheet 3, fill down, fill right.
3. The cells that are different
   between Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 will now say "difference" in Sheet 3.

You could adjust the formula to show the actual values that were different.

Comment: This one was the easiest solution to get working with my dataset.

Answer (score 13):

**Excel has this built in** if you have an excel version with the *Inquire add-in*.

[This link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-HA102835926.aspx) from office webpage describes the process of enabling the add-in, if it isn't activated, and how to compare two compare two workbooks - among other things.

The comparison shows both structural differances as well as editorial and a lot of other changes if 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-HA102835926.aspx

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in the Mac version of Excel.

Comment: This is not available in all versions. It looks like it's only in 2016 Premium. Certainly not available to my subscription.

Answer (score 13):

you should try this free online tool - [www.cloudyexcel.com/compare-excel/](http://www.cloudyexcel.com/compare-excel/)

works good for most of the time, sometimes the results are a little off.

plus it also gives a good visual output

[image]

You can also download the results in excel format. (you need to signup for that)

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. Maybe my dataset of 500x30 cells was too large.

Comment: Also, it requires you to upload data to their website - not viable if you need to keep your data private

Comment: This was the best answer for my situation. I don't care that I have to upload the file and the visual feedback is soo helpful.

Answer (score 8):

`COUNTIF` works well for quick difference-checking. And it's easier to remember and simpler to work with than `VLOOKUP`.

```
=COUNTIF([Book1]Sheet1!$A:$A, A1)
```

will give you a column showing 1 if there's match and zero if there's no match (with the bonus of showing >1 for duplicates within the list itself).

Comment: This process will work, and will be less work for the user.  In terms of computing power, a VLOOKUP is more efficient unless you are checking for duplicate values as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013, you can use **Microsoft Spreadsheet Compare** to run a report on the differences between two workbooks.

*Launch Spreadsheet Compare*:

In Windows 7: On the Windows Start menu, under Office 2013 Tools, click Spreadsheet Compare.

In Windows 8: On the Start screen, click Spreadsheet Compare. If you do not see a Spreadsheet Compare tile, begin typing the words Spreadsheet Compare, and then select its tile.

*Compare two Excel workbooks:*

1. Click Home > Compare Files.
2. a. Click the blue folder icon next to the Compare box to browse to the location of the earlier version of your workbook. (In addition to files saved on your computer or on a network, you can enter a web address to a site where your workbooks are saved.)
3. b. Click the green folder icon next to the To box to browse to the location of the workbook that you want to compare to the earlier version, and then click OK. (TIP You can compare two files with the same name if they're saved in different folders.)
4. In the left pane, choose the options you want to see in the results of the workbook comparison by checking or unchecking the options, such as Formulas, Macros, or Cell Format. Or, just Select All.

*Reference:*

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Basic-tasks-in-Spreadsheet-Compare-f2b20af8-a6d3-4780-8011-f15b3229f5d8

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11222643)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, thanks for the note, I updated the answer with the essential parts from the source

Comment: @JacobKalakalJoseph I tried this method, but it does not compare the contents if the rows are not ordered, and just compares the row numbers. Such a pity, unless I'm using this tool incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `vlookup` function.

Put both sets of data in the same excel file, on different sheets. Then, in the column next to the 805 row set (which I assume is on sheet2), enter

```
=if(isna(vlookup(A1, Sheet1!$A$1:$A$800, 1, false)), 0, 1)
```

The column will contain 0 for values that are not found in the other sheet, and 1 for values that are. You can sort the sheet to find all the missing values.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best option is a freeware app called Compare IT!  .... absolutely brilliant utility and dead easy to use.  http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3.htm

Comment: I am not sure if the web site working any more? Some of the images are broken and I was unable to download the app.

Answer (score 3):

SO in fact that you are using excel means that you can use the 
[SpreadSheet Compare](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205148.aspx) from Microsoft. It is available from Office 2013. Yes i know this question is older then 6 years. But who knows maybe someone need this information today.

Comment: This feature only comes with Office Professional Plus 2013.

Answer (score 3):

The Notepad++ compare plugin works perfectly for this.  Just save your sheets as .csv files and compare them in Notepad++.  Notepad++ gives you a nice visual diff.

Answer (score 2):

May be this replay is too late. But hope will help some one looking for a solution

What i did was, I saved both excel file as CSV file and did compare with Windiff.

Answer (score 2):

[ExcelDiff](http://msws.co/en/product03.jsp) exports a HTML report in a Divided (Side-by-side) or Merged (Overlay) view highlighting the differences as well as the row and column.

Answer (score 1):

I used Excel Compare. It is payware, but they do have a 15 day trial. It will report amended rows, added rows, and deleted rows. It will match based on the worksheet name (as an option):

http://www.formulasoft.com/excel-compare.html

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting to highlight the differences in excel.

**[Here's an example.](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=69841)**

Comment: The problem here is that every single cell after the first occurrence of a difference will then be highlighted.  True, you could fix the first occurrence to find the next one.  But you'll have to redrag the formula after each fix, and if you have a lot of differences, this is simply infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

With just one column of data in each to compare a PivotTable may provide much more information. In the image below ColumnA is in Sheet1 (with a copy in Sheet2 for the sake of the image) and ColumnC in Sheet2. In each sheet a source flag has been added (Columns B and D in the image). The PT has been created with [multiple consolidation ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651) (`Sheet1!$A$1:$B$15` and `Sheet2!$C$1:$D$10`):

[image: SO1500153 exaple]

The left hand numeric column shows what is present in Sheet1 (including `q` twice) and the right what in Sheet2 (again with duplicates – of `c` and `d`). `d-l` are in Sheet1 but not Sheet2 and `w` and `z` are in Sheet2 (excluding those there just for the image) but not Sheet1. Add display `Show grand totals for columns` and control totals would appear.

Answer (score 0):

I found this command line utility that doesn't show the GUI output but gave me what I needed: https://github.com/na-ka-na/ExcelCompare

Sample output (taken from the project's readme file):

```
> excel_cmp xxx.xlsx yyy.xlsx
DIFF  Cell at     Sheet1!A1 => 'a' v/s 'aa'
EXTRA Cell in WB1 Sheet1!B1 => 'cc'
DIFF  Cell at     Sheet1!D4 => '4.0' v/s '14.0'
EXTRA Cell in WB2 Sheet1!J10 => 'j'
EXTRA Cell in WB1 Sheet1!K11 => 'k'
EXTRA Cell in WB1 Sheet2!A1 => 'abc'
EXTRA Cell in WB2 Sheet3!A1 => 'haha'
----------------- DIFF -------------------
Sheets: [Sheet1]
Rows: [1, 4]
Cols: [A, D]
----------------- EXTRA WB1 -------------------
Sheets: [Sheet1, Sheet2]
Rows: [1, 11]
Cols: [B, K, A]
----------------- EXTRA WB2 -------------------
Sheets: [Sheet1, Sheet3]
Rows: [10, 1]
Cols: [J, A]
-----------------------------------------
Excel files xxx.xlsx and yyy.xlsx differ
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to find a tool that will help to extract only the different sheets with the cell difference highlighted. Could not find any, so ended up writing one for myself. I hope this helps someone who is looking for similar solution. It takes care of left/right unique sheets, identical/different size sheets.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Get a complete list of sheets from both WorkBook
BOOK1 = "Book_1.xlsx"
BOOK2 = "Book_2.xlsx"

xlBook1 = pd.ExcelFile(BOOK1)
sheetsBook1 = xlBook1.sheet_names
xlBook2 = pd.ExcelFile(BOOK2)
sheetsBook2 = xlBook2.sheet_names

sheets = list(set(sheetsBook1 + sheetsBook2))

with pd.ExcelWriter('Difference.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', mode='w') as writer:
    for sheet in sheets:
        print (sheet)

        book1 = None
        book2 = None
        book1Exists = True
        book2Exists = True

        try:
            book1 = pd.read_excel(BOOK1,sheet_name=sheet,header=None,index_col=False).fillna(' ')
        except ValueError as ve:
            book1Exists = False
        try:
            book2 = pd.read_excel(BOOK2,sheet_name=sheet,header=None,index_col=False).fillna(' ')
        except ValueError as ve:
            book2Exists = False

        # Case 1: Both sheet exist and they are identical size
        if ( (( (book1Exists == True) and (book2Exists == True) )) and 
            ( (len(book1) == len(book2)) and (len(book1.columns) == len(book2.columns)) )):


                comparevalues = book1.values == book2.values
                if False in comparevalues:
                    rows,cols = np.where(comparevalues==False)

                    for item in zip(rows,cols):
                        book1.iloc[item[0],item[1]] = ' {} --> {} '.format(book1.iloc[item[0], item[1]], book2.iloc[item[0],item[1]])

                    book1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet,index=False,header=False)
                    
                    # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
                    workbook  = writer.book
                    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet]
                    
                    # Add a format. Light red fill with dark red text.
                    format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                                                   'font_color': '#9C0006'})

                    # Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
                    worksheet.conditional_format('A1:AZ100',{'type':     'text',
                                                  'criteria': 'containing',
                                                  'value':    '-->',
                                                  'format':   format1}) 

        # Case 2: Left unique case        
        elif (book1Exists == False):
            book2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet+" B2U",index=False,header=False)
        
        # Case 3: Right unique case        
        elif (book2Exists == False):
            book1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet+" B1U",index=False,header=False)
        
        # Case 4: Both exist but different size
        elif (( (book1Exists == True) and (book2Exists == True) ) and 
            ( (len(book1) != len(book2)) or (len(book1.columns) != len(book2.columns)) )):
            if (book1.size > book2.size):
                book1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet+" SD",index=False,header=False)
            elif (book2.size > book1.size):
                book2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet+" SD",index=False,header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if you want to identify values not present in larger set or to check in the larger set if the value is present in the shorter one. Here a solution for both cases:

Values in Subset not in Set

```
=FILTER(B2:B11,ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B11,A2:A6,0)))
```

Check if value in Set is not in Subset

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B11,A2:A6,0)), TRUE, FALSE)
```

[image: sample excel file]

Answer (score -1):

excel overlay will put both spreadsheets on top of each other (overlay them) and highlight the differences.

http://download.cnet.com/Excel-Overlay/3000-2077_4-10963782.html?tag=mncol