# filter excel worksheet based on records form a 2nd sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel file that is a SEO report of a website. But the tool that generated the report included everything under the sun and most of it is junk. I want to filter out the important info such that I keep only records in the first worksheet that correspond to a record in a second worksheet.

Basically I want to keep all the records in the first sheet where the URL matches a URL in the "good url" list found on worksheet2.

Is there some cell formula I can use or macro or something???
Please explain how to implement the solution as it’s been a while since I used excel in any advanced way.

See the attached file for reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a `VLOOKUP` function with an autofilter.  The `VLOOKUP` function helps "link" data in two different sheets.  See my explanation on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051610/compare-two-excel-sheets/3054438#3054438).