# Excel - How to Delete All rows from 1 sheet that do not contain column input from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of email addresses in 1 sheet in my Excel Book that are on Column M (Sheet1) with 2050 rows long (there is other data on other columns, such as First and Last Name, etc.), and another Sheet (Sheet2) that have a list of email addresses in Column A (210 rows long).  I need to keep all email addresses in Sheet1 - Column M (need to keep entire row) that match with the email addresses in Sheet2 - Column A, but need to remove all other rows where email addresses that do not match from Sheet2 column A with Sheet1 - Column M.

Is there a formula to do this?

Or Perhaps it can create another sheet (Sheet3) with the rows from Sheet1 that match Sheet1 - Column M with Sheet2 - Column A?

Thanks very much.

Comment: A formula cannot Delete a Row. Formulas cannot change another cell, with the exception of when the other cells have references to the cell with the function. A function alone cannot modify another cell though, not without either condition statemens or VBA COde

Comment: Perhaps it can create another sheet with the rows from Sheet1 than?  That would be even better IMHO.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500153/find-the-differences-between-2-excel-worksheets/1500222#1500222

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one method but doesn't use just a formula:

Setup an additional column as in "N" below. and fill using a similar formula

[image]

- Turn on filtering for your sheets and filter for "no"

  - data --> filtering click on drop down for "N" and un-select yes/blanks
- now place cursor in cell aX (where x will be the first row that is no)
- press ctrl-end to highlight all rows that are "No"
- Now press delete.

Or you can copy and paste the "YES" using filtering to another sheet.

I believe the crux of the issue here was identifying the records that didn't match which the formula in the image above: and here: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M5,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Yes","No")` does

Comment: I don't have a CTRL+END key on my keyboard.  I see CTRL, but no END.

Comment: OMG, you ROCK, it worked.  I just filtered by "YES" value!  Thanks a million!!!!!

Comment: For future reference this is more of a "power user" function than it is a programming one.  You may find more help and better examples there: http://superuser.com/